# Fetch params from controller when nesting attributes 2 levels deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

My `Pack` model has lines, which in turn contain items, and both pack and lines accept nested attributes for the collection they contain.

Here are the models:

```
Class Pack < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :pack_lines, dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :pack_lines, allow_destroy: true
end

Class PackLine < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :pack
   has_many :pack_line_items, dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :pack_line_items, allow_destroy: true
end

Class PackLineItem < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :pack_line
end
```

It took me a long time finding the right syntax to use to `permit` the nested nested parameters in my controller.

Comment: I had initially started this as a question, but I finally managed to solve my problem so I posted the results. And Kumar's reply actually showed an even simpler way. The question was: "How do I permit nested parameters for an object already itself nested?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can permit nested attributes like this.

```
params.require(:pack).permit(
  :name,
  pack_lines_attributes: [
    :id, :_destroy, pack_line_items_attributes: [
         :id, :_destroy
    ]
  ]
)
```

They work similarly for `has_many` and `has_one`. You might have to singularize in case of `has_one` like `pack_line_attributes [:id]`

Answer (score 0):

After much head-scratching and docs-reading, here is what I came up with:

```
# In controllers/packs_controller.rb
def pack_params
   params.require(:pack).permit(
      :name,
      pack_lines_attributes: [
         :id,
         :_destroy,
         {
           pack_line_items_attributes: [
             :id,
             :_destroy
           ]
         }
      ]
   )
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Why do you have the `{}` inside `pack_lines_attributes`??

Comment: @Kumar You're definitely right! The `{}` were leftover from an issue I had with incorrect indices when generating line items. Your answer is better than my own :-)